# Bash - regex to extract airway bill numbers

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a text file with some airway bill numbers in it:

```
Pesanan anda telah dikirim oleh jasa pengiriman NinjaVanID dengan nomor resi NLIDRT0000399000
Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI. no.resi 885000210000. Cek status pesanan di https://example.com/resi/
Pesanan telah dikirim melalui JNE. no.resi JNRP-0000708000. Cek status H+1 di www.example.co.id or atau menghubungi 021-2927.0000
Pesanan anda telah dikirim oleh jasa pengiriman LEX ID dengan nomor resi LXRP-9295841000
```

I want to extract these airway bill numbers:

```
NLIDRT0000399000
885000210000
JNRP-0000708000
LXRP-9295841000
```

Here are the rules:

1. The prefixes `NLIDRT` `JNRP-` `LXRP-` are always the same, only the numbers behind them are different
2. 885000210000 this one doesn't have any prefix, only numbers, they always change.
3. The rest of the text doesn't change. Only the AWBs that change.

This is what I have tried so far but doesn't work:

```
grep -e 'NLIDRT\K(\d+)' -e 'TIKI, no\.resi \K(\d+)' -e 'JNRP-\K(\d+)' -e 'LXRP-\K(\d+)' awb.txt
```

How do I do this? The command doesn't matter, it can be awk / grep / sed

Comment: Try [`grep -oE '(NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}'`](https://ideone.com/VgSp3b). I assume those AWBs that have no letter prefixes consist of 10 or more digits.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you break down the regex ?

Comment: The main point is the `-o` option; without it, you'll get the whole line containing the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PCRE compatible patterns, where [`\d` matches digits](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and `\K` is a [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that omits the whole text matched so far. That is not what you need since the prefixes are part of your  expected matches.

I suggest using

```
grep -oE '(TIKI\. *no\.resi *|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}'
```

The `-o` option makes `grep` return the substrings matched, not the whole lines where a match occurred.

The POSIX ERE pattern (due to `-E` option) matches

- `(TIKI\. *no\.resi *|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?` - an optional (1 or 0 times) substring:

  - `TIKI\. *no\.resi *` - `TIKI.`, then 0+ spaces, `no.resi`, and 0+ spaces (replace spaces with `[[:space:]]` to match any whitespace)
  - `|` - or
  - `NLIDRT` - `NLIDRT` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `JNRP-` - `JNRP-` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `LXRP-` - `LXRP-` substring
- `[0-9]{10,}` - 10 or more digits.

**Note**: If these AWBs are to be matched as whole words (if there are no letters, digits and `_` chars "glued" to them), you may use **word boundaries**:

```
grep -oE '\b(TIKI\. *no\.resi *|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}\b'
```

or

```
grep -oE '\<(TIKI\. *no\.resi *|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}\>'
```

where `\b` is a location in string between a word/non-word char, or between start of string and a word char, or a word char and the end of string, and `\<` matches  a place between a non-word char/start of string and a word char (leading word boundary) and `\>` is a closing word boundary (place between a word and a non-word char/end of string.

See the [grep demo online](https://ideone.com/iPSS57)

```
s='Pesanan anda telah dikirim oleh jasa pengiriman NinjaVanID dengan nomor resi NLIDRT0000399000
Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI. no.resi 885000210000. Cek status pesanan di https://www.jne.co.id/resi/
Pesanan telah dikirim melalui JNE. no.resi JNRP-0000708000. Cek status H+1 di www.jne.co.id or atau menghubungi 021-2927.8888
Pesanan anda telah dikirim oleh jasa pengiriman LEX ID dengan nomor resi LXRP-9295841000'

echo "$s" | grep -oE '(TIKI\. *no\.resi *|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}'
```

Result:

```
NLIDRT0000399000
TIKI. no.resi 885000210000
JNRP-0000708000
LXRP-9295841000
```

Comment: What if I want to put `(TIKI)` in front of `885000210000` so I can tell which shipping service this AWB belongs to, how do I do it? the result should be `(TIKI) 885000210000`

Comment: @Joe Add it as an alternative: [`grep -oE '(\(TIKI\)[[:space:]]*|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}'`](https://ideone.com/q68FMx). Note that in POSIX ERE, to match literal `(` and `)` chars, you need to escape them.

Comment: @Joe I provided a demo link - https://ideone.com/q68FMx - it works. I do not know what you tried, please provide your demo link. Probably, you need to add a comma, I see you have a comma there, in your pattern.

Comment: it works only if that text is stored in a variable, it doesn't when the text is stored in a file. Try storing that text in a file and run the grep again.

Comment: @Joe What exact text? As in my https://ideone.com/q68FMx demo link? `cat t | grep -oE '(NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}'` returned `NLIDRT0000399000`, `885000210000`, `JNRP-0000708000`, `LXRP-9295841000`, `885000210000`. `cat t | grep -oE '(\(TIKI\)[[:space:]]*|NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)?[0-9]{10,}'` returns `NLIDRT0000399000`, `885000210000`, `JNRP-0000708000`, `LXRP-9295841000`, `(TIKI) 885000210000`. **It works**. Please add the exact text in your file and grep command into the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173242/discussion-between-joe-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

- Example:

  ```
  grep -Eo '\<((NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{12})\>' <<\eof
  Pesanan anda telah dikirim oleh jasa pengiriman NinjaVanID dengan nomor resi NLIDRT0000399000
  Paket telah dikirim melalui TIKI. no.resi 885000210000. Cek status pesanan di https://example.com/resi/
  Pesanan telah dikirim melalui JNE. no.resi JNRP-0000708000. Cek status H+1 di www.example.co.id or atau menghubungi 021-2927.0000
  Pesanan anda telah dikirim oleh jasa pengiriman LEX ID dengan nomor resi LXRP-9295841000
  eof
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  NLIDRT0000399000
  885000210000
  JNRP-0000708000
  LXRP-9295841000
  ```
- Explanation:

  ```
  grep -Eo '\<((NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{12})\>'
  ```
- `\<` means beginning of word (so that we don't start matching inside a           word; for example we shouldn't match `XJNRP-`)
- There are two alternatives: `(` with prefix or `|` without prefix `)`
- The variant with prefix is `(NLIDRT|JNRP-|LXRP-)[0-9]{10}`, that is, one of `(` `NLIDRT` or `JNRP-` or `LXRP-` `)` followed by 10 digits.
- The variant without prefix is 12 digits.
- `\>` means end of word, so that we don't match longer digit sequences or something like `...89XX`.

Note that `grep -E` enables extended regular expressions.

Note that the 10 and 12 digit rules are my impression, and could be wrong. If you want one or more digits (instead of 10 and 12), say `[0-9]+`. If you want 10 or more say `[0-9]{10,}`.

Comment: Can you please explain the regex ?

Comment: You really have to stop asking that, he already provided full code and he already did in his answer.  Some effort is required on your part.